# Error: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:27017]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, deployd

I am working on Deployd application. Suddenly Mongodb server stopped working and showing the error **Error: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:27017]**  .

Following are the log entries in mongodb.log file

```
Thu Dec 11 03:59:14 [conn286] end connection 127.0.0.1:55014 (60 connections now open)
Thu Dec 11 03:59:16 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55015 #287 (61 connections now open)
Thu Dec 11 03:59:16 [conn287] end connection 127.0.0.1:55015 (60 connections now open)
Thu Dec 11 03:59:22 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55016 #288 (61 connections now open)
Thu Dec 11 03:59:22 [conn288] end connection 127.0.0.1:55016 (60 connections now open)
Thu Dec 11 03:59:32 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55017 #289 (61 connections now open)
Thu Dec 11 04:00:00 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55018 #290 (62 connections now open)
Thu Dec 11 04:00:01 got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
Thu Dec 11 04:00:01 **[interruptThread]** now exiting
Thu Dec 11 04:00:01 dbexit: 
Thu Dec 11 04:00:01 [interruptThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Thu Dec 11 04:00:01 [interruptThread] closing listening socket: 6
Thu Dec 11 04:00:01 [interruptThread] closing listening socket: 7
Thu Dec 11 04:00:01 [interruptThread] closing listening socket: 8
Thu Dec 11 04:00:01 [interruptThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
Thu Dec 11 04:00:01 [interruptThread] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Thu Dec 11 04:00:01 [interruptThread] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Thu Dec 11 04:00:01 [interruptThread] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Thu Dec 11 04:00:01 [interruptThread] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Thu Dec 11 04:00:01 [interruptThread] shutdown: final commit...
Thu Dec 11 04:00:01 [interruptThread] shutdown: closing all files...
Thu Dec 11 04:00:01 [interruptThread] closeAllFiles() finished
Thu Dec 11 04:00:01 [interruptThread] journalCleanup...
Thu Dec 11 04:00:01 [interruptThread] removeJournalFiles
Thu Dec 11 04:00:01 [interruptThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Thu Dec 11 04:00:01 dbexit: really exiting now


***** SERVER RESTARTED *****


Thu Dec 11 04:00:02 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=22882 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=ip-172-31-26-132
Thu Dec 11 04:00:02 [initandlisten] db version v2.2.3, pdfile version 4.5
Thu Dec 11 04:00:02 [initandlisten] git version: f570771a5d8a3846eb7586eaffcf4c2f4a96bf08
Thu Dec 11 04:00:02 [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-2-29-40 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 17:48:28 EST 2009 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Thu Dec 11 04:00:02 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", dbpath: "/var/lib/mongodb", logappend: "true", logpath: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log" }
Thu Dec 11 04:00:02 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongodb/journal
Thu Dec 11 04:00:02 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Thu Dec 11 04:00:02 [initandlisten] 
Thu Dec 11 04:00:02 [initandlisten] ERROR: Insufficient free space for journal files
Thu Dec 11 04:00:02 [initandlisten] Please make at least 3379MB available in /var/lib/mongodb/journal or use --smallfiles
Thu Dec 11 04:00:02 [initandlisten] 
Thu Dec 11 04:00:02 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 15926 Insufficient free space for journals, terminating
Thu Dec 11 04:00:02 dbexit: 
Thu Dec 11 04:00:02 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Thu Dec 11 04:00:02 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Thu Dec 11 04:00:02 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Thu Dec 11 04:00:02 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Thu Dec 11 04:00:02 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Thu Dec 11 04:00:02 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Thu Dec 11 04:00:02 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Thu Dec 11 04:00:02 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Thu Dec 11 04:00:02 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
Thu Dec 11 04:00:02 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Thu Dec 11 04:00:02 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Thu Dec 11 04:00:02 dbexit: really exiting now


***** SERVER RESTARTED *****


Thu Dec 11 05:00:01 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=24935 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=ip-172-31-26-132
Thu Dec 11 05:00:01 [initandlisten] db version v2.2.3, pdfile version 4.5
Thu Dec 11 05:00:01 [initandlisten] git version: f570771a5d8a3846eb7586eaffcf4c2f4a96bf08
Thu Dec 11 05:00:01 [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-2-29-40 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 17:48:28 EST 2009 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Thu Dec 11 05:00:01 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", dbpath: "/var/lib/mongodb", logappend: "true", logpath: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log" }
Thu Dec 11 05:00:01 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongodb/journal
Thu Dec 11 05:00:01 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Thu Dec 11 05:00:01 [initandlisten] 
Thu Dec 11 05:00:01 [initandlisten] ERROR: Insufficient free space for journal files
Thu Dec 11 05:00:01 [initandlisten] Please make at least 3379MB available in /var/lib/mongodb/journal or use --smallfiles
Thu Dec 11 05:00:01 [initandlisten] 
Thu Dec 11 05:00:01 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 15926 Insufficient free space for journals, terminating
Thu Dec 11 05:00:01 dbexit: 
Thu Dec 11 05:00:01 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Thu Dec 11 05:00:01 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Thu Dec 11 05:00:01 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Thu Dec 11 05:00:01 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Thu Dec 11 05:00:01 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Thu Dec 11 05:00:01 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Thu Dec 11 05:00:01 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Thu Dec 11 05:00:01 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Thu Dec 11 05:00:01 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
Thu Dec 11 05:00:01 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Thu Dec 11 05:00:01 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Thu Dec 11 05:00:01 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Please help me out.

Comment: "Please make at least 3379MB available in /var/lib/mongodb/journal or use" is the point. Mongo allocate all the disk space, as it configured on the start

Answer (score 1):

Thu Dec 11 04:00:02 [initandlisten] Please make at least 3379MB available in /var/lib/mongodb/journal or use --smallfiles

Looks like you don't have enough free space.